# Mule: Response code 405 mapped as failure

Tags: mule, mule-esb

i have mule app which keeps calling another Mule API too many times. In the logs of Mule API i see below message

In the client mule app i see error 
Response code 405 mapped as failure only for few requests. (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)

please suggest how this can be solved in Mule . 
I am using Mule 3.8.5

Comment: Can you share your related HTTP config and flow configuration? It seems the API you are calling returns a `405 Method Not Allowed`, are you sure you are calling your API with the proper parameters?

Comment: Error response is clear that you are sending invalid Method.

Comment: its is Mule interface and from this interface Mule API is gettting called many times. I get this error only for few requests, so i am not able to understand what is going wrong

Comment: <flow name="saveDesign" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_SaveDesign" path="${saveDesign.path}" method="POST" doc:name="saveDesignHTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="client_id" value="${saveDesignClientId}"/>
                <http:query-param paramName="client_secret" value="${saveDesignClientSecret}"/>
                
                <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
    </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
    </flow>

Comment: <http:request-config name="HTTP_SaveDesign"  host="${saveDesign.host}" port="${saveDesign.port}" responseTimeout="${saveDesign.timeout}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" connectionIdleTimeout="40000" protocol="HTTPS">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:trust-store insecure="true"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:request-config>  --> this is connector config

Comment: @Pierre B : its is Mule interface and from this interface Mule API is gettting called many times. I get this error only for few requests, so i am not able to understand what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

mule api was running on 0.1Vcore on cloudhub, cpu utilization was below 50% and memory usage was below 50%.... but still I increased vcore to 0.2vCore and it solved my problem.... 
my colleagues also said this is known problem,, by increasing vCores solves problem even though current vCores utilization is less